# How lazy can R be? eg. Lazily reading a portion of a file into R based on downstream operations

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

### Synopsis:

I am trying to understand if there are/what the limits to `R`'s lazy-ness. As in, what are the walls that are independent of implementation. I use a hopefully useful example below.

#### setting the scene:

I often have flat files (1E9 to 1E11 rows) like the example file `file.txt`:

```
"chr\tstart\tend\nchr1\t1\t2\nchr1\t2\t3\nchr2\t3\t4\nchr2\t1\t2\nchr3\t2\t3\nchr3\t3\t4\n"
```

i.e.

```
readr::read_tsv("file.txt")

#>  Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
#>  
#>     chr start end
#>  1 chr1     1   2
#>  2 chr1     2   3
#>  3 chr2     3   4
#>  4 chr2     1   2
#>  5 chr3     2   3
#>  6 chr3     3   4
```

But with the real files I will often **sample** and/or **filter** the contents immediately (sometimes for performance, sometimes as the analysis only targets a subset of the observations).

Continuing with `file.txt` I may do in a `dplyr` way:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- readr::read_tsv("file.txt") %>% sample_n(3)
df2 <- readr::read_tsv("file.txt") %>% filter(chr == "chr2")
df3 <- readr::read_tsv("file.txt") %>% group_by(chr) %>% sample_n(1)
```

or equivalently use `data.table`'s `dt <- fread("file.txt")[...]`.

#### the question:

`R` is awesomely lazy but can it be so lazy as to only actually read in what's specified by the downstream operations? I'm asking if there is a limit to R's laziness or is it just a matter of implementation? And if so, is it all up to the implementer to figure out the shortest path or does R have any tools to help you along the way?

#### N.B.

I am aware that there are a number of ways of reading in a subset of observations in a file both on the R side and outside of R (`R.utils::readTable`,`pipe(...)`,...)  before/as you read it in. I'm not asking if this has been implemented in `R`, I'm asking can it be and if so does `R` help or is it all up to the implementer to do this?

Comment: Is it possible? Yes, I think so (but not without involving code on the C level). Is there any implementation? Not that I know of. It's easy to use other tools (e.g., SQL) and an implementation would be not trivial.

Comment: How would `R` know whether a given line of text meets the downstream criterion without first reading that line?  Are you asking for a filter app that, perhaps, readsf a line into an ephemeral object, tests it, and only copies that object into your output array when the condition is met (and then reads a new line into the object)?